# Is there a way to close command prompt after pytest suite execution is complete?

Tags: python-3.x, windows, batch-file, cmd, pytest

I am currently facing an issue where when I execute my pytest suite from the command line (in windows).
I have added my pytest call in a bat file.

```
py.test TestCases/test_macro.py --url %1 --html=Reports/macro-community-suite-%fullstamp%.html --css=css/style.css --self-contained-html --host %2 --type=macro
echo mail_call
call send_mail.bat
```

What happens is, after pytest has generated results (for ex: 2 tests passed), the command window stays there itself, it is not terminating. Hence the next command which sends mail is not getting executed.

My question, therefore, is, how to kill the cmd after pytest has completed execution and results have been generated?

Comment: you would need to exit the python script when the results have been generated. then call send mail.

Comment: @GerhardBarnard: How would I do that? How do I exit the script?

Comment: I would need to see the `python` script in order to help, but typically it should be something like at the end of the function `quit()`

Comment: If the default behavior of py.test is to remain open waiting for the user to press a key or close the console window, then I would expect it at least has a command-line option to force it to exit immediately after the test.

Comment: FYI, the window is a console window, not a "cmd" window. It's created by the host process for the console session, an instance of conhost.exe. cmd.exe is just another console app, no different from python.exe, powershell.exe, etc.